# geom_GeomLabel() has yet to be implemented in plotly

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plotly

I am getting this error when converting a ggplot to plotyly.
What has to be done?

My code :

```
p  <- ggplot(data_, aes(data_$dates,group = 1)) +
      geom_point(aes(y = data_$exp))+
      geom_point(aes(y = data_$actual))+
      geom_line(aes(y = data_$exp, color='Expected')) + 
      geom_line(aes(y = data_$actual, color='Actual'))+
      geom_label(aes(y = data_$exp,label = data_$exp,hjust = 0,vjust = -0.2))+
      geom_label(aes(y = data_$actual,label = data_$actual,hjust = 0,vjust = 0.2 ))+
      labs(title = "Avail")+
      labs(x="Dates")+
      labs(y="")+
      guides(color = guide_legend(title = ""))

output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({
 ggplotly(p)
  })
```

Error I am getting :

```
geom_GeomLabel() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
Warning in origRenderFunc() :
  Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "85055e160099"; Shiny doesn't use them
```

Answer (score 2):

The error means that `plotly` at this point cannot handle `geom_label` from `ggplot2`. One thing that can be done is, as the error suggests, to open an issue at https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues. However, it happens that `geom_text` does work, so replacing `geom_label` by it would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @qwww, does it answer your question?